# Error Installing Truffle in VS Code?

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, remix, ganache

I'm trying to install truffle on VS Code(in window 10) after installing node.js, npm and ganache.
All the above three have been installed and worked but When I tried to install truffle in VS Code in terminal, these kinds of errors occurring again and again. What should I do?
[image: This is the first pic when I tried to install it]

These two are the error pictures.

[image: Error pic1]

[image: Error pic2]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the version of `node` and `npm` first. I had this error before, solving by changing `npm` version to v6 and `node` version to v16.

Comment: Emily Li, I have installed the latest version of  node and npm. But this is still occurring.

Comment: I mean lastest version may bring to these errors. You may try to downgrade it.

Comment: Currently, my npm version is 8.5.5 and node is v16.15.0. Which version should I install.

Comment: run `npm install -g npm@6` in terminal will change the version of npm to v6